# Could I use a bridge rectifier with a capacitor to make a measurable DC voltage to measure the output of the detector coil in an NMR?

Tags: bridge-rectifier

I'm making an nuclear magnetic resonance (NMR) detector.

I'm wondering if I could use an bridge rectifier along with an capacitor to smooth out the output to DC. Then I could measure it with an Arduino or ESP32. This could also let me measure way higher frequencies. Is this possible and what would be the downsides?

Comment: NMR stands for 'Nuclear Magnetic Resonance' (applicable to Nuclear Magnetic Resonance Spectroscopy). References: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_magnetic_resonance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_magnetic_resonance_spectroscopy

Comment: So you can't "make an NMR".

Comment: You can make an NMR at home, it's been done but with a really expensive oscilloscope. This question is a cross between chemistry and eletrical engineering so I might move this to chemistry.

Comment: the output is a tiny voltage in a tight range of frequencies. You need to digitse and filter

Comment: I seem to remember a home NMR experiment written up in (maybe) Scientific American years ago.  It was pretty limited, but it demonstrated the principles.  If I can find a link I'll post it.

Comment: Here's a reference to the article, I guess subscribers can access it.  However, Google provides other examples of home made NMR setups.  https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/the-amateur-scientist-1959-04/

Comment: I saw a few but they all use oscilloscopes since they have them laying around, I don't really have the money for a oscilloscope though.

Comment: You would need impossibly fast and impossibly low-voltage diodes for this. In other words, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

But you can consider radio receiver techniques, such as mixing and down-conversion.  Since the NMR signal spans some ~ppm, if the center frequency is say a modest 30MHz, 10ppm of which is 300Hz, so it could be mixed with 29.999MHz to give an intermediate frequency of 1kHz with ±300Hz bandwidth, which is easily acquired by such a platform.

Comment: Thanks for answering!